# Транслитерация: "Тбилиси" -> "Tbilisi"

Tags: python

```
from transliterate import translit
text = "Тбилиси"
translit(text, 'en')
print(text)
```

Как сделать чтобы он перевел слово Тбилиси, в английский регистр, чтобы получилось "Tbilisi". Но только в том случае если это слово в русском регистре.

Comment: вам нужно с английского на русский или на оборот?

Comment: С русского на английский. Но только в том случае если само слово на русском

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import transliterate
name_input = input("Введите значение ")
try:
    name = transliterate.translit(name_input, reversed=True)
except transliterate.exceptions.LanguageDetectionError:
    name = name_input

print(name)
```

[Проверка](https://repl.it/repls/FrenchAdorableEngine)

```
> Введите значение  Hello World Привет мир
Hello World Privet mir
```

Comment: Как хорошо что в Питоне есть куча нативных готовых решений)) НО! Что если мне нужно заменить прочие символы на нижнее подчеркивание? Например, для ЧПУ?

Comment: @DaemonHK не особо понял какие прочие символы, но если под ними вы понимаете что то вроде (!?+;:"*#$_&) то это можно регулярной функцией сделать без проблем да и русские буквы тоже можно регуляркой заменить

Answer (score 2):

```
print(translit(u"Тбилиси", 'ru', reversed=True))
Tbilisi
```